# Problem reading cosmosDB files in VS code due to : in filename

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-cosmosdb

I am storing integration logs in CosmosDB which have a timestamp in the filename including a ":" character. I'm not able to open the files in VS code because of this (and maybe the "." character as well). I found a github issue talking about this, but that issue is closed and I'm still not able to open the files. Need some guidance on what I can do to open this files from inside VS code. Yes, I could change the filename but I'd prefer just to make it work. I can open fine in the Azure Portal.

Example file name: 2019-09-04T14:38:35.308Z
Error message: "ENOENT:no such file or directory"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `:` character is an illegal filename character on Windows machines. So, if you're on Windows, I suspect that would be your issue. Special characters in filenames, such as `:`, are usually frowned upon.

Comment: I understand that but I'm wondering if there is a way to have those illegal characters replaced when using the VS Code extension but leave them as is in the DB. I'm just using the standard ISO timestamp as the filename and would rather not change it as currently I can grab that to query our middleware if I need more information about a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a limitation based on allowable Windows filenames, so the option is either to rename the file or accept that I cannot read this files within VS Code and use Azure Storage Explorer instead.

I'm happy to accept a different answer if anyone out there has any other options!